# Calling methods of actual object instead of parent class

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following dummy code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>

 using namespace std;

 class Parent {
 public:
     void printHello() {
         cout << "Hello Parent" << endl;
     }
 };

 class Child : public Parent {
 public:
     void printHello() {
         cout << "Hello Child" << endl;
     }
 };


 int main() {
     vector<Parent*> list;
     Child child;
     list.push_back(&child);

     list[0]->printHello();
  }

  Output: Hello Parent
```

I am trying to create a list of objects of classes derived from the parent class. Iterating over them and running a method they all inherit and override.

I had assumed the method in the child class would have overridden the method in the parent class.

I have also tried the approach of using `vector<Parent>` instead of `vector<Parent*>`.

The result has been the same. How can I call the methods of the derived classes instead of the parent class?

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/virtual-functions `<-- read this`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ you have to use **virtual** in the parent class method definition to specify that you are going to use a polymophic method. The default behavior in C++ is not polymorfic.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Parent {
public:
    virtual void printHello() {
        cout << "Hello Parent" << endl;
    }
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    void printHello() {
        cout << "Hello Child" << endl;
    }
};
```

Check this out for more info: [Polymorphism in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/)

Answer (score 5):

Use virtual methods - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual. Read more about them [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/virtual-functions).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Parent {
public:
    // using virtual keyword
    virtual ~Parent() = default;
    virtual void printHello() const { std::cout << "Hello Parent" << std::endl; }
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    // using override keyword though its not necessary
    void printHello() const override { std::cout << "Hello Child" << std::endl; }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<Parent *> list;
    Child child;
    list.push_back(&child);

    list[0]->printHello();
}
```

[**Output**](https://www.ideone.com/bdMNjC) -

> Hello Child

Answer (score 0):

To get the behavior you want, that method needs to be declared `virtual` in the parent class. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual for more information.